# Laravel Foreign Key Constraint Errors when deleting Parent with data in child of child

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys

So here's how this is set up.

- A Step has a Category
- A Category has a Section
- A Section has Multiple Questions

I **thought** I had everything working in my model files, but unfortunately I'm running into an integrity error with my foreign keys.

My models are named:

```
Step.php
StepCategory.php
StepSection.php
StepQuestion.php
```

I'm not really sure how to set up my "many to one" relationships, or what belongs to what.

My database table names are as follows:

```
steps

step_categories

step_sections

step_questions
```

I'm running into this error when i'm deleting the parent entry of anything... If i delete a step, it should delete a category, the sections, and the questions associated with them. If i delete a category, it should delete the section and questions. If i delete a section it deletes all the questions.

In my `step_categories` table i have the foreign key column named as `step_id`.

In my `step_sections` table i have the foreign key column named as `category_id`.

In my `step_questions` table i have the foreign key column named `section_id`.

My foreign key name on my `step_categories` table is `step_categories_step_id_foreign`.

My foreign key name on my `step_sections` table is `step_sections_category_id_foreign`.

My foreign key name on my `step_questions` table is not set up yet as I have yet to make that part of the site yet. I'm currently stuck on the sections portion.

My `destroy()` function in my `StepsController.php` file is:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // Find the step by the ID
    $step = Step::find($id);

    // Find all the categories and delete them.
    $step->category()->delete();

    // Delete the step
    $step->delete();

    // Flash the Session
    Session::flash('success', 'The step has been successfully deleted.');

    // Return Redirect to the index page
    return redirect()->route('steps.index');
}
```

Heres how my models look so far... This is as far as I've gotten... :(

`Step.php`

```
class Step extends Model
{
    // Tell the model what table to use
    protected $table = 'steps';

    // Define the relationship between steps and step categories
    public function category() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StepCategory');
    }

}
```

`StepCategory.php`

```
class StepCategory extends Model
{
    // Tell the model what table to use
    protected $table = 'step_categories';

    // Define the relationship between step categories and steps
    public function step() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Step', 'id', 'step_id');
    }

    // Define the relationship between steps categories and sections
    public function section() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StepSection');
    }

}
```

and my `StepSection.php`

```
class StepSection extends Model
{
    // Tell the model what table to use
    protected $table = 'step_sections';

    // Define the relationship between step sections and step categories
    public function category() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\StepCategory', 'id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

So thats legit as much information as I can possibly give that I think will solve the problem. If you need anymore information to help me set up these relationships let me know.

So far I can delete a Step, and it will delete the category, so long as the category has no sections attached to it. However I can't delete the Step, or Category if it has any sections attached to it. :/ Don't know whats going on.

Comment: Have you added ondelete - cascade in your migration for the foreign keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is because of your tables, so make sure that when you declare a foreign key in your migrations you are adding what should be done on delete/update of those rows. For example:

On your step_categories the foreign key 'step_id' should be like this:

```
$table->foreign('step_id')->references('id')->on('step')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

You should do the same following with all your tables